# Open source tools for testing purpose in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, testing

Currently i am using Mac OS X 10.6.4 and i want to know what are the tools(automated & manual) that i can install in my mac for testing purpose.Generally i need this for different kind of Website & Mobile platform testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of [open source tools for testing](http://opensourcetesting.org/functional.php). Many are cross platform and will work on Mac.

Specifically, I recall watching the demo of [Project Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/) which looks very innovative and simple to use. It is work in progress, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Ottomate](http://download.cnet.com/OttoMate-Web-Test-Automator-Actions/3000-2247_4-76110.html) is one that I saw seemed pretty interesting.  It might only be for Safari though unfortunately.  [Eggplant](http://download.cnet.com/Eggplant/3000-2247_4-49073.html?tag=mncol;8) is another one as well.  I'm trying to find a solution to this problem as well.